# controller not defined - but why?

Tags: angularjs

so while working with this fine rails-angular [tutorial](http://angular-rails.com/find_and_browse.html)

I do this in my app.js

```
var receta = angular.module('receta',[
    'templates',
    'ngRoute',
    'controllers'
]);
...
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('RecipesController', RecipesControllerFunc);
RecipesController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location'];
//^ ^ ^ ^ gives me `RecipesController is not defined`
function RecipesControllerFunc($scope,$routeParams,$location){
    $scope.search = function(keywords) {
        $location.path('/').search('keywords', keywords)
    }

    if($routeParams.keywords){
        keywords = $routeParams.keywords.toLowerCase();
        $scope.recipes = recipes.filter(function(recipe){
            return (recipe.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords) != -1)
        })
    } else {
        $scope.recipes = [];
    }
    console.log(recipes);
};
```

I've used this `$inject` syntax in other projects with no problem, and `controllers` is certainly defined...
[image]

So why isn't RecipesController being defined here?

P.S. When I use the usual *'dependencies + function in an array'* syntax, everything works. But I want the `$inject` syntax to work.

Comment: `RecipesController.$inject` should be `RecipesControllerFunc.$inject`

Answer (score 1):

You have typo.
You have been registered the function `RecipesControllerFunc` but you trying to inject the services to `RecipesController` which are not exists I guess.

I can't see the code in the middle so ... I hope it gave you the direction.

**UPDATE:** I changed `RecipesController` function name to the right one which is `RecipesControllerFunc`.

```
var receta = angular.module('receta',[
    'templates',
    'ngRoute',
    'controllers'
]);
// Some middle code
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('RecipesController', RecipesControllerFunc);
RecipesControllerFunc.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location'];
//^ ^ ^ ^ gives me `RecipesController is not defined`
function RecipesControllerFunc($scope,$routeParams,$location){
    $scope.search = function(keywords) {
        $location.path('/').search('keywords', keywords)
    }

    if($routeParams.keywords){
        keywords = $routeParams.keywords.toLowerCase();
        $scope.recipes = recipes.filter(function(recipe){
            return (recipe.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords) != -1)
        })
    } else {
        $scope.recipes = [];
    }
    console.log(recipes);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If `RecipesControllerFunc` does not exist in the middle part of your code, then the error is in how you registered `RecipesController` without `RecipesControllerFunc` being defined.

---

Try this:

```
var receta = angular.module('receta',[
    'templates',
    'ngRoute',
    'controllers'
]);
...
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
function RecipesControllerFunc($scope,$routeParams,$location){
    $scope.search = function(keywords) {
        $location.path('/').search('keywords', keywords)
    }

    if($routeParams.keywords){
        keywords = $routeParams.keywords.toLowerCase();
        $scope.recipes = recipes.filter(function(recipe){
            recipe.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords) != -1
        })
    } else {
        $scope.recipes = [];
    }

};

controllers.controller('RecipesController', RecipesControllerFunc);
RecipesController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location'];
```

Comment: Thanks. RecipesControllerFunc was defined and now it is showing.

Comment: You have to declare `RecipesControllerFunc` before you register it as a controller. Meaning, your function declaration must come first before the controller registration. Will edit answer.

Comment: I moved things around and still no joy https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/lkj2dewi3ofvkgc/9ilzceap.jpg Maybe this technique just stopped working with some recent Angular update.

Comment: That's odd. Can you make a plunkr out of it?

Comment: Thanks... I'll use the usual syntax for now.